# Can @ID column accept same id values while fetching records from database

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have a class like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTCOURSE")
public class Trainee {

    private String studentId;
    private Date sessionDateTime;
    ....

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Student_Id")
    public String getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "Session_Date_Time")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getSessionDateTime() {
        return sessionDateTime;
    }

    public void setSessionDateTime(Date sessionDateTime) {
        this.sessionDateTime = sessionDateTime;
    }

    ....

} //end of class Trainee
```

I am quering from database that gives me resultset like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Trainee> findTraineeFromLegacy(String courseId, String fromDate, String toDate) throws Exception {

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(FIND_TRAINEE_LEGACY, Trainee.class);
    return query.setParameter("courseId", courseId)
            .setParameter("fromDate", fromDate)
            .setParameter("toDate", toDate)
            .getResultList();

} //end of findTraineeFromLegacy()
```

I want to ask suppose if same `Student_Id` exist in the database. Like 3 `Student_Id` of same value 2,2,2 exist in the database. Then while fetching records from database, does Trainee class raise any exception ?

Because `Student_Id` is marked with `@id` annotation and `Id` should be unique. I am only fetching records. I won't send any record to database.

Thanks.

**Edit
-----------------**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;

CREATE TABLE employee (
    id INT ,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    salary BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO employee(id, name, salary) VALUES (1, 'Basit', 70000);
INSERT INTO employee(id, name, salary) VALUES (1, 'Masood', 65000);
INSERT INTO employee(id, name, salary) VALUES (1, 'Kazim', 35000);
```

Employee Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private long salary;

    public Employee() { 
    }

    public Employee(int id) { 
        this.id = id; 
    }

    //getter and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id = " + id + " : name = " + name + " : salary = " + salary; 
    }

} //end of class Employee
```

EmployeyServicess

```
@Lazy
@Service("employeeServices") 
@Repository
@Transactional
public class EmployeeServicesImpl implements EmployeeServices {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="mySql_emf")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAllEmployees() {

        TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e", Employee.class);
        return query.getResultList();

        //Query emQuery = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee", Employee.class);
        //return  emQuery.getResultList();

    } //end of findAllEmployees();

} //end of end of class EmployeeServicesImpl
```

Employee Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String springXmlFile = "classpath:spring/app-context-xml.xml";
    GenericXmlApplicationContext springContext = SpringUtil.loadSpringContext(springXmlFile);

    EmployeeServices employeeServices = springContext.getBean("employeeServices", EmployeeServices.class);

    // find all employees
    List<Employee> emps = employeeServices.findAllEmployees();
    for (Employee e : emps){
        System.out.println("Found employee: " + e);
    }

} //end of main()
```

output:

```
Hibernate: select employee0_.id as id1_0_, employee0_.name as name2_0_, employee0_.salary as salary3_0_ from Employee employee0_
Found employee: id = 1 : name = Basit : salary = 70000
Found employee: id = 1 : name = Basit : salary = 70000
Found employee: id = 1 : name = Basit : salary = 70000
```

JDBC

```
@Lazy
@Service("jdbcManager") 
@Repository
@Transactional
public class JdbcDatabaseManager {

    public List<Employee> findAllEmployees() {  
        List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM employee";
        Connection connection = null;
        try {   
            connection = getMySqlConnection();  
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {  
                Employee employee = new Employee();

                int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
                String name = resultSet.getString("name");
                Long salary = resultSet.getLong("salary");

                employee.setId(id);
                employee.setName(name);;
                employee.setSalary(salary);;

                result.add(employee);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            String errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeConnection(connection);
        }

        return result;

    } //end of findAllEmployees()

} //end of class JdbcDatabaseManager
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ...
    // find all employees
    List<Employee> emps = employeeServices.findAllEmployees();
    for (Employee e : emps){
        System.out.println("Found employee: " + e);
    }

    System.out.println("JDBC");
    System.out.println();

    JdbcDatabaseManager jdbcManager = springContext.getBean("jdbcManager", JdbcDatabaseManager.class);
    List<Employee> jdbcEmps = jdbcManager.findAllEmployees();
    for (Employee e : jdbcEmps){
        System.out.println("Found employee: " + e);
    }
```

output:

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM employee
Found employee: id = 1 : name = Basit : salary = 70000
Found employee: id = 1 : name = Basit : salary = 70000
Found employee: id = 1 : name = Basit : salary = 70000
JDBC

Found employee: id = 1 : name = Basit : salary = 70000
Found employee: id = 1 : name = Masood : salary = 65000
Found employee: id = 1 : name = Kazim : salary = 35000

} //end of main
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Validation is done mostly at the database, so if your records have the same ID, JPA is not likely to catch the problem and throw an exception.  But there will be problems - you will have 3 database rows for different data.  JPA will think those 3 rows are really the same entity, and so only return 1 entity 3 times.  You will not know which of the 3 rows that entity represents.

Comment: What is it that you are really after?  If userId isn't the primary key in the database, why is it being marked as the ID?

Comment: @Chris Actually the query is made by some one else and in the beginning i thought `Student_id` is the primary key. But then he said to me that there may be same `studetnt_id` exist fro more than one records. So verify if this is the case then JPA will accept it or throw any exception ... I asked for primary key in the query, he said we are just fetching records from database ... In the query there are joins .. Right now i don't have the data to test, that's why i asked this question

Comment: From the table name, it seems like a relation table between student data and course.  My guess is that student_id and sessiondate will uniquely identify rows, since a student can only be enrolled in a session once.  Mark both as a composite pk and it will work if so.  Otherwise, as mentioned, a query may bring back multiple rows for a studentid, but JPA will give you a single entity instance which won't reflect the database values for the other rows.

Comment: I just did an experiment and yes you are right it gives me three records but they are same :(.

Comment: Why don't JPA behaves like JDBC. JDBC giving me three records correctly while JPA don't. Is there any way by which i get the same result with JPA in this case as i am getting with JDBC? Thanks

Comment: Yes, map it properly so that rows are uniquely identified so that unique entities can be built.  Or, return raw data instead of entities.  The point of JPA is different from JDBC, so if all you want is JDBC behaviour, stick with it.  JPA is used for entities, to track changes to them, manage relationships etc.  if all you want is rows from some table once and don't take the time to map it, it's overkill for your needs.

Comment: HHmm thanks. What do you mena by `return raw data instead of entities.`. What can be raw data in this case ?